# Show loginform if not logged in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have a login form on index.php.

What I want is that on this page, if you are already logged in, the html form should not appear. If you are logged in, you should on index.php could see your username and with a logout button.

And if you're not logged in, this form should appear:

```
<form action="<?php $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post" >
            <h1>Login Form</h1>
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username)" required="" id="username" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
                <a href="#">Lost your password?</a>
                <a href="#">Register</a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Someone who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can store some value in a session variable on login.

And then above the page you can check it.

If its available that means the user is already logged in and you don't need to show the login form.

If not then show the login form.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Session` for this and Store `Username` in Session

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
?>

<form action="<?php $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post" >
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" id="username" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
        <a href="#">Lost your password?</a>
        <a href="#">Register</a>
    </div>
</form>

<?php 
    }
    else
    {
        Welcome, echo $_SESSION['username'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. keep username in session and check at top of your page that the session is already set or not. If yes then they are logged in and what ever you want to do you can. And if not then show your login form...

Answer (score 0):

use session in login page and at the start of every page check the session
like in login page do this on the top

```
session_start();
```

and after selecting the fields from database store them in session like

```
$_SESSION['username'];
```

then, on every page check session like

```
if(!array_key_exists('username',$_SESSION)){
header("location:index.php");
}
```

Comment: why you are using `header`? he is already on `index.php` page

Comment: header is used in some other page
first two parts for the index page and third part for any othe page to validate the session